# Is there any way to swap a bot by a specific bot name in CS:CZ?

Tags: counter-strike-condition-zero

I play Counter-Strike: Condition Zero game. When I play around total 50-60 rounds, one of my bot gets swapped automatically with a *Easy* bot.

For example, *Maverick* is swapped by *Kenny*.

Now, I can kick the new bot, but again someone else joins.

So, is it a bug in game. If yes is there any way to fix it?

If there's no fix, is there any command to swap the bot with a specific original bot?

For example, can I do something like: ?

```
kick Kenny; bot_add_ct Maverick;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay! Problem solved.

I don't know if it's a bug or something else, but I found the solution.

Earlier, as I said, when you kick the automatically joined player, a new player was automatically joined again. That was the problem.

**This problem occurs when you close the console.**

But when you kick the player and don't close the console, and type the next command to add the original bot, it basically 'swaps' it. Which I wanted. So the entire bot list is same again.

You may want to read the console here:

[image]

---

EDIT: It isn't likely a bug I think. Because I've noticed that it happens only when one bot kills other bot in his team. The maximum number is I think 3 or 4. Once a bot kills his teammate (bot) more than this, he'll be kicked automatically.

Comment: If you resolved your problem, you might want to check this answer as the [accepted answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).